# How to create searchable Content Types?

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, sharepoint-search, modern-document-library

I created a document library with quite a large number of content types which I also display as a column in the library, e.g. *Brochures*, *Photos*, *Technical Manuals*, etc. However, if someone types "brochure", "photo" or "technical manual" into the SharePoint search bar, none of these documents get listed. For other columns which contain different information about the files, e.g. *Product Line* or *Application*, this problem does not exist and that information is searchable. So it occurred to me that I probably need to enable the searchability of content types somehow. Does anyone here have a clue how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Content types are crawled in SharePoint Online by default. You can see this by going to the "Manage Search Schema" page normally found at:

```
https://yourtenant-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/searchadmin/ta_listcrawledproperties.aspx?level=tenant
```

The crawled property for content types is `ows_ContentType` which is mapped to the managed properties `ContentType` and `SPContentType`.

I don't believe these managed properties are searchable but you can map `ows_ContentType` to your own managed properties which you could make searchable.